# Why is ActiveConnectionCount doubled in Amazon CloudWatch metrics when using WebSockets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

If we run a WebSocket load test with a max of 10K open connections we always get double the ActiveConnectionCount, the included image is a screenshot of a CloudWatch metric of the Application Load Balancer of our wss://endpoint. If we run a HTTP load test the ActiveConnectionCount is correct. Why is this?

**Pseudo Load test code:**

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
const client = new WebSocket('wss://endpoint');

client.on('open', () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    client.send('random message');
  }, 15000);
});
```

}

**Screenshot of ActiveConnectionCount in Amazon CloudWatch Metrics:**

[image: ActiveConnectionCount Amazon CloudWatch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the AWS docs, ActiveConnectionCount is "The total number of concurrent TCP connections active from clients to the load balancer ***and*** from the load balancer to targets."

So if you have 10 connections through a load balancer to a target, this metric should show 20 connections (10 from clients, and 10 to targets).